# Include layout inside ConstriansLayout

Tags: android

I have a layout with an image and a text and i want to include this layout inside another Constrains layout
this is the code:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_face_circle" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/DrawerButtonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/bt_emotion_entry_text" />
</merge>
```

and this is the parent constrains layout:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bt_hp_emotions"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            layout="@layout/bt_emotions_entry"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the problem is that the layout doesn't get constraints correctly to the parent

[image]

all layout constrains to the top left
i included a few layouts

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the design editor how the layout behaves?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using "merge" but if you change it to "RelativeLayout" or anything else you are fine.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <include
    android:id="@+id/bt_hp_emotions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/test"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want use merge tag you need change your xml like this :

parent xml :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

    <include layout="@layout/bt_emotions_entry"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

your child xml layout  :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_face_circle" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DrawerButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/bt_emotion_entry_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView" />
</merge>
```

And I suggest you read the following document for better understanding Re-using layouts concept.

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts